# Insert a value containing single quotes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

How do I insert a value in MySQL that consist of single or double quotes. i.e

```
Ali said, "This is Ashok's Pen."
```

The single quote will create problems. There might be other escape characters.

I am using php to enter data into the database?

How do you insert the data properly?

Comment: read [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: You need to escape it somehow. Use mysqli_real_escape_string or even better PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: *"I am using php to enter data into the database?"* - I don't know, are you?? show your code for the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\` (Escape) character to insert single quotes and double quotes.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(`clomn1`) VALUES ('Ali said, "This is Ashok\'s Pen."')
```

Comment: What's with the escaping of commas and double quptes?

Comment: You need to use \ (Escape) character to insert single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: First that doesn't explain the comma, second, that applies to quotes of the same kind as the encapsulation, not of every quote available.

Comment: You need to use \ (Escape) character to insert single quotes and double quotes also to insert comma as well. `single quotes and double quotes` is what OP want.

Comment: No you don't. You need it for the `'` in `Ashok\'s`, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I have edited

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Manual: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. It wasn't my downvote though.

Comment: @Kostas Mitsarakis Yes you are correct. edited with mysqli_real_escape_string